# Run NUnit tests in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nunit

Is it possible? (It seems not. Does it not support NUnit? What should I use instead?)

Here is my test project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.17.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TheProjectToBeTested\TheProjectToBeTested.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And here is my `azure-pipelines.yml`

```
pool: 'TFSBuild'

variables:
# The web app will not build because it is netcore3.1 and the server only supports netcore3.0.
  solution: '**/*Build.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

# I added this and I don't undertand it.
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\*test*.dll
     !**\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform*
     !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

However the tests don't get run.

```
##[section]Starting: VSTest
==============================================================================
Task         : Visual Studio Test
Description  : Run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test (VsTest) runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as MsTest, xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah (for JavaScript tests using QUnit, Mocha and Jasmine), etc. can be run. Tests can be distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).
Version      : 2.153.9
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest
==============================================================================
SystemVssConnection exists true
SystemVssConnection exists true
SystemVssConnection exists true
Running tests using vstest.console.exe runner.
======================================================
Test selector : Test assemblies
Test filter criteria : null
Search folder : E:\TFS\8\s
VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
Attempting to find vstest.console from a visual studio installation.
Run in parallel : false
Run in isolation : false
Path to custom adapters : null
Other console options : null
Code coverage enabled : false
Diagnostics enabled : false
SystemVssConnection exists true
Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe
========================================================
Test selector : Test assemblies
Test assemblies : **\Release\*test*.dll,**\Release\**\*test*.dll,!**\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform*,!**\obj\**
Test filter criteria : null
Search folder : E:\TFS\8\s
Run settings file : E:\TFS\8\s
Run in parallel : false
Run in isolation : false
Path to custom adapters : null
Other console options : null
Code coverage enabled : false
Diagnostics enabled : false
Rerun failed tests: false
VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
Attempting to find vstest.console from a visual studio installation.
========================================================
======================================================
[command]"E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" @E:\TFS\_temp\126341f1-33c9-11eb-a545-b3a68600e11b.txt
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.3.0-preview-20190715-02
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

vstest.console.exe 
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\TheProjectToBeTested.Test.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.Utilities.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\cs\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\cs\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\cs\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\de\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\de\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\de\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\es\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\es\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\es\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\fr\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\fr\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\fr\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\it\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\it\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\it\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ja\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ja\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ja\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ko\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ko\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ko\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\pl\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\pl\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\pl\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\pt-BR\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\pt-BR\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\pt-BR\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ru\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ru\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ru\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\testhost.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\tr\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\tr\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\tr\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\zh-Hans\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\zh-Hans\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\zh-Hans\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\zh-Hant\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\zh-Hant\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll"
"E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\zh-Hant\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
/logger:"trx"
/TestAdapterPath:"E:\TFS\8\s"
Starting test execution, please wait...
Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.
TheProjectToBeTested.Test.dll is built for Framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0 and Platform AnyCPU.
Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.dll is built for Framework .NETStandard,Version=v2.0 and Platform AnyCPU.
Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.dll is built for Framework .NETStandard,Version=v2.0 and Platform AnyCPU.
Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.dll is built for Framework .NETStandard,Version=v2.0 and Platform AnyCPU.
Microsoft.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.dll is built for Framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1 and Platform AnyCPU.
Microsoft.TestPlatform.Utilities.dll is built for Framework .NETStandard,Version=v2.0 and Platform AnyCPU.
NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll is built for Framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1 and Platform AnyCPU.
testhost.dll is built for Framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1 and Platform AnyCPU.
Go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236877&clcid=0x409 for more details on managing these settings.

No test is available in E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\TheProjectToBeTested.Test.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.Utilities.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\cs\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\cs\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\cs\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\de\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\de\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\de\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\es\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\es\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\es\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\fr\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\fr\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\fr\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\it\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\it\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\it\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ja\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ja\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ja\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ko\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ko\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ko\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\pl\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\pl\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\pl\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\pt-BR\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\pt-BR\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\pt-BR\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ru\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ru\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\ru\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\testhost.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\tr\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\tr\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\tr\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\zh-Hans\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\zh-Hans\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\zh-Hans\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\zh-Hant\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\zh-Hant\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll E:\TFS\8\s\TheProjectToBeTested.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\zh-Hant\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
Results File: E:\TFS\8\s\TestResults\TFSBUILD$_TFSBUILD_2020-12-01_11_33_48.trx

No Result Found to Publish 'E:\TFS\8\s\TestResults\TFSBUILD$_TFSBUILD_2020-12-01_11_33_48.trx'.
##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
##[section]Finishing: VSTest
```

Comment: Not get your latest information. Just want to check whether below answers are helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to leave comment below.

Answer (score 11):

Please move rather to [dotnet command and instead of using VSTest run it using this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops#run-your-tests):

> If you have test projects in your repository, then use the .NET Core task to run unit tests by using testing frameworks like MSTest, xUnit, and NUnit.

```yaml
steps:
# ...
# do this after other tasks such as building
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: @RichardBarraclough first do not add keyword `steps`, second you must set `projects` accordingly to your solution. It could be as above, but not necessarily.

Comment: Got it going, but it just hangs.

Comment: Try moving all your steps into dotnet tasks. You can find example [here](https://github.com/kmadof/devops-manual/blob/master/dotnet-core-on-windows/build.yaml) or in docs linked above

Comment: Why should they be dotnet steps? Is the out-of-the-box template wrong?

Comment: Template is fine, but it works out of the box with MSTest and not with NUnit or xUnit. I tried to configure VSTest to run NUnit test, but each time the same - tests are not found. Which is strange because if I run loccally vstest.console.exe all is fine.

Comment: It seems that the VS* tasks are rubbish and it's best to use `dotnet` or `PowerShell` tasks.

Comment: I think that this is not worth to spend so much time to configure it. If there is no clear path to achieve this and on the other hand you can use sth what simply just works and works on both linux and windows host agent (and you should observe faster runs on linux) you can benefit from that. Of course I recommend to use linux host agent if you host your app on linux.

Comment: Does not work to run DLL files (precompiled)

Comment: @NiKiZe there is no reason why it should not work. You only need to be sue you have a correct path to your dll. Also there is a flagg `--no-build` `Doesn't build the test project before running it. It also implicitly sets the - --no-restore flag.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test

Comment: Testing with calling dlls (no csproj) did not work, so gave up on that path. But thanks might investigate further in the future if needed.

Answer (score 2):

> Run NUnit tests in Azure DevOps pipeline

To test `.Net Core` dlls with `Visual Studio Test` task, please try to add following additional settings of Visual Studio Test task:

- Path to vstest.console.exe: `E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform`.
- Other console options: `/framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0"`:

  [image]

Comment: These options failed for me:

2021-06-06T18:22:04.3534084Z Description  : Run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test (VsTest) runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as MsTest, xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah (for JavaScript tests using QUnit, Mocha and Jasmine), etc. can be run. Tests can be distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).
2021-06-06T18:22:04.3534840Z Version      : 2.170.1
...snip...
2021-06-06T18:22:06.4779338Z ##[error]VsTest task failed.

Comment: These options may have failed for me because my unit tests are .NET 5.0. I can try different console options.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe missing NUnit3TestAdapter package in one of project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
   <package id="NUnit" version="3.10.1" targetFramework="net45" />
   <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

After adding package this task was running all nunit tests

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .net core application as you do, the other answer using DotNetCoreCLI@2 with test command is the correct answer.

However, if you are using framework and don't want to use VSTest or really have to use nunit there is another way to get this to work.

You can use the pipeline with a docker container that has nunit in. You can use the [code from here](https://github.com/gabrielaraujof/nunit-console-dockerfile/blob/master/Dockerfile) which is a mono image that has nunit added. A requirement of Azure Devops is there is no entry point so you will need to use your own copy without the last line.

Once you have your container you can then [run your pipeline in a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops)
and use a bash command block

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '/nunit/nunit3-console.exe **/*Tests/*.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```